# Can't manage to have service trigger onServiceConnected call

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have this problem where the onServiceConnected method is not called, and I have tried multiple solutions but none of them worked...

My service management code boil down to this:

```
public class BackgroundMediaManagerCommunicator {
private Messenger   service = null;
private boolean     isBound = false;
private Context     context;
final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case PLAYLIST:
                playlist = playlist.getClass().cast(msg.obj);
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        service = new Messenger(binder);
        android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManagerCommunicator: Attached service");
        isBound = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        isBound = false;
        service = null;
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManagerCommunicator: Unexpected disconnection, Trying to reconnect");
    }
};

public BackgroundMediaManagerCommunicator(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public boolean connect()
{
    return context.getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), BackgroundMediaManager.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

public void disconnect() {
    if (isBound) {
        context.unbindService(connection);
        isBound = false;
    }
}

public boolean ready()
{
    return isBound;
}
```

and my service:

```
public class BackgroundMediaManager extends Service {
final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case PLAY:
                android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager: Received Play");
                play(playlist.get(msg.arg1));
                idPlaying = msg.arg1;
                break;
            case SET_PLAYLIST:
                android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager: Received Set playlist");
                playlist = playlist.getClass().cast(msg.obj);
                break;
            case GET_PLAYLIST:
                android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager: Received Get playlist");
                try {
                    msg.replyTo.send(Message.obtain(null, BackgroundMediaManagerCommunicator.PLAYLIST, (Object)playlist));
                } catch (RemoteException e)
                {
                    android.util.Log.d(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager: severe case of ded client");
                }
                break;
            case SET_VIEW:
                android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager: Received set view");
                setDisplay((SurfaceHolder)msg.obj);
                break;
            case PAUSE:
                android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager: Received pause");
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                else
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case NEXT:
                android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager: Received next");
                move(1);
                break;
            case PREVIOUS:
                android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager: Received previous");
                move(-1);
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};

public BackgroundMediaManager()
{
    super();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager Bound");
    return messenger.getBinder();
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    startCommand();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startCommand();
    return START_STICKY;
}
private void startCommand()
{
    android.util.Log.v(TAG, "BackgroundMediaManager created");
    mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(onVideoSizeChanged);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And is called like this from the main activity:

```
if (!mediaManagerCommunicator.connect())
        startService(new android.content.Intent(this, BackgroundMediaManager.class));
    while (!mediaManagerCommunicator.connect()) { try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception e){} };
    outOfCreateReadying.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!mediaManagerCommunicator.ready()) { try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception e){} };
        }

    }, 100);
```

and my manifest relating to the service:

```
<service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="vdragon.epiplayer.BackgroundMediaManager"
        android:process=":remote">
    </service>
```

(pkg name is 'vdragon.epiplayer')

It systematically get stuck in the while (!mediaManagerCommunicator.ready()) { try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception e){} }; part for no obvious reason (by that i mean i tried all the solutions proposed on the two first pages when googling 'onServiceConnected not called android'), and i can't seem to find a combination that works correctly:

The only progress i made so far is getting the messages "BackgroundMediaManager Bound" and "BackgroundMediaManager created" to show up on the log.

Comment: you dont need `while (!mediaManagerCommunicator.connect())` part, just call `connect` once, what does it return?

Comment: do you see in the logcat: `BackgroundMediaManager Bound`? BTW what is the point in calling `context.getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: Yes, i see it. context.getApplicationContext()was one of the fix i found, and since it made no difference i just left it in there?

Comment: so if `onBind` is called then `onServiceConnected` should be called as well, if not, try to debug it returning a simple `Binder` from `onBind`

Comment: I just tried that: the service is still created then bound correctly, but onServiceConnected is still not called

Comment: so did you try http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html ? just follow official docs, not any hanging tutorials from different sources

Comment: Yes, the code is based on the messenger example...

Comment: why do you have `final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());` in `BackgroundMediaManagerCommunicator` ? for testing just call `bindService` with Actuvuty context, on the Service side just return `new Binder()`

Comment: In the complete code, BackgroundMediaManagerCommunicator also have a messenger, which is passed in the 'replyTo' field of the message for when the service need to send messages to the application. What you describe is what i just did and i got the same result.

Comment: do you have to use Messenger? AIDL is not good enough?

Comment: try this minimalist code: http://pastebin.com/x1z4KEJC and see the logcat

Comment: and? what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: I made an application that implement that code, and it returns false there; it doesn't bind

Comment: Woops, i had put the service tag in manifest out of the application tags, it returns true now. And it calls on ServiceConnected (in the minimal code from the pastebin)

Comment: so now return messenger's Binder

Comment: That IS what i had tried when you first asked me to return a simple binder instead of the messenger binder. The only difference between the testing application is that the connect is not done in onCreate...

Comment: it shouldn't matter where you call bindService, what API level are you running that code?

Comment: so your code calls bindService in onCreate?

Comment: I made both projects with the same parameters, but i don't know which api level that is... Yes bindService is called via onCreate in the main activity. I have moved it to the handler postpone in the code i have now because i read it may cause onServiceConnected to not be called, and yet that didn't change anything.

Comment: i checked that, it doesnt matter, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Additional_Notes): you can call `bindService` wherever you want

Comment: I reduced BackGroundMediaManager to the 'onBind' function, and BackgroundMediaManagerCommunicator to 'connect'... It still doesn't work.

Comment: so find the difference with my code that works